# Parse error: syntax error unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a problem with this string

```
'Require.www' => false
```

This code gives me the error:

```
>Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\xampp\KERNEL-DOCMS\Server.Config.php on line 5
```

How can I fix this? It's in the serverconfig of a online game.

The complete code is:

```
## URL
$Config['URL'] =
    'Default' 
        'Require.www' => false, // www.example.com
        'SSL.enabled' => true, // https://
        'Server' => '***', // public server
        'Lang' => 'en_US' // GLOBAL.
    ,   
    'Other' => 
        //'example.com' => ['Require.www' => false, 'SSL.enabled' => false, 'Lang' => 'es_ES', 'MySQL' => ['host' => '127.0.0.1','user' => 'root','pass' => '','dbname' => 'cmsdb']]
    ,
    'devPrivateServer' => 'localhost' // private developer server
;

## SQL Server Data
$Config['MySQL'] = 
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'user' => '***',
    'pass' => '***',
    'dbname' => 'do'
;
// Do not tuch the code below this text if yuo do not know what yuo're doing
           define( "DB_DSN", "mysql:host".$Config['MySQL']  ['host'].";dbname".$Config['MySQL']['dbname']."");//this constant will
define ( "DB_USERNAME", $Config['MySQL']["user"] ); //username of database
define ( "DB_PASSWORD", $Config['MySQL']["pass"] ); //username of database
define ( "CLS_PATH", "class" ); //the class path of our project
```

Comment: you are not showing the relevant code. Provide the complete statement.

Comment: to expand on the last comment, errors like these can show the line number after the actual error, as a missing symbol at the end of the previous line can cause the next line to be invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly syntax errors. If you want to declare an array, you either use `array()` or the shorthand `[]`:

```
$Config['URL'] = array(
    'Default' => array(
        'Require.www' => false, // www.example.com
        'SSL.enabled' => true, // https://
        'Server' => '***', // public server
        'Lang' => 'en_US' // GLOBAL.
    )   
    ,   
    'Other' => ''
        //'example.com' => ['Require.www' => false, 'SSL.enabled' => false, 'Lang' => 'es_ES', 'MySQL' => ['host' => '127.0.0.1','user' => 'root','pass' => '','dbname' => 'cmsdb']]
    ,
    'devPrivateServer' => 'localhost' // private developer server
);

$Config['MySQL'] = array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'user' => '***',
    'pass' => '***',
    'dbname' => 'do'
);
```

Comment: Thanks, the error was fixed, but now there's another error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in C:\xampp\KERNEL-DOCMS\Server.Config.php on line 5  how can i fix this one?

Comment: @Joyfabio line 5? post the current codes you're using. just use this answer an apply it to yours, this should have no problems at all

Comment: The error is always about 'Require.www' => false, // www.example.com with this code

Comment: @Joyfabio are you sure you're using this answer now? seems fine here http://codepad.viper-7.com/0Eqhmv

Comment: I was wrong, it worked, maybe i copied bad something